# extracting a price value from xml within <span

Tags: xml-parsing

I've been trying to extract the price ($26.86) from the following

```
            <div class="pdp-details-spec-row">
                <div class="pdp-details-spec-name">
                    Price:
                </div>
                <div class="pdp-details-spec-value">
                    <span class="pdp-main-price"> 

                            <span id="listPriceDiv">$26.86 ea.</span>&nbsp;
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

using the following on google spreadsheets:

=IMPORTXML("URL", "//span[@class='listPriceDiv']")

I've also tried ("URL", "//span[id='listPriceDiv']") and about another 1000 combinations.

The url of the website is: www.mscdirect.com/product/details/89350300

Does anyone see any obvious mistakes in the code?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you want to fix:

1. you need to include the http:// prefix on the url your using in your function or google won't pull in the data.
2. you xpath query should be: //*[@id='listPriceDiv']
3. The final formula looks like this: 
   =IMPORTXML("http://www.mscdirect.com/product/details/89350300","//*[@id='listPriceDiv']")